# Question that get's edited later on with the answer

Tags: discussion

I just stumbled upon this question: [IN-clause in HQL or Java Persistence Query Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828049/in-clause-in-hql-or-java-persistence-query-language), where the asker edited the question and added the answer there (the question had an accepted answer though). It this suitable to the SO format? Shouldn't the asker add this a separate answer and accept that if the answer added in the edit solved his problem?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on if the OP is active enough, you can do one of two things:

- Ask them to remove the answer from the question and post it as an answer of its own volition, or
- Create a community wiki answer with the OP's contents - and be sure to reference where you got the answer from.

Answers embedded in a question aren't useful; they make it harder to find the actual answer.